# How set watermark behind text in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf, watermark

is there who can help me, i had a problem with the watermark in fpdf

Here is my code:

```
$width_header = array(10,45,25,60,20,15,15);
$set_align    = array('L','L','L','L','R','L','R');
$table_head   = array('No.','Kelompok','Kode Brg','Nama Barang','QTY','','Cek list');
$page_copy    = 0;
$fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);

$lebar = $fpdf->w;

$fpdf->line($fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), $fpdf->GetX()+$lebar-18, $fpdf->GetY());
$fpdf->Ln(2);
$fpdf->SetWidths($width_header);
$fpdf->SetAligns($set_align);
$fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++) {
    $fpdf->Row_Header($table_head);
}
$fpdf->line($fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), $fpdf->GetX()+$lebar-18, $fpdf->GetY());

$no        = 1;
$sub_total = 0;
$sql2 = $this->adm_entry_penjualan_model->getDataCetakDetil(" WHERE a.hps<>'*' AND a.no_bukti='$no_bukti_tmp' AND a.tgl='$tgl_tmp' ORDER BY b.acct_no, b.kode_sub");

$fpdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

foreach ($sql2->result_array() as $key_no => $row2) {
        //Put the watermark
        $fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',50);
        $fpdf->SetTextColor(255,222,233);
        $fpdf->RotatedText(90,90,'COPY',45);
        $fpdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $fpdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
        $fpdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $fpdf->Row(
        array($no++,
        $row2['acct_name'],
        $row2['kode_sub'],
        $row2['nama_sub'],
        $row2['qty'].' ',
        $row2['satuan'],
        '...'
    ));

    $fpdf->line($fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), $fpdf->GetX()+$lebar-18, $fpdf->GetY());

}
```

I want a result like this image:

[image: image 1]

but it looks like this image:

[image: image 2]

what should I change in order to get the results I want

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your watermark code in the `Header()` function as shown in [this example](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script9.php). That way the watermark will be set on `AddPage()`, i.e. before the actual content is output, making the watermark appear in the "background".